# Is it possible to use Google Analytics on watchos ext?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, watchos-2

I'm working on an watchOS 2.0 extension and I want to use Google Analytics to track the watchos app navigation.

I'm using cocoapod.

[The Google podspecs](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/Google/1.1.0/Google.podspec.json) isn't compatible with watchos. Is there another version compatible (cocoapod or not)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently. The current [Analytics SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/) currently does not support bitcode which is required for watchOS. However, you could use the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en) to send hits directly.

Comment: Since I posted this [Analytics SDK 3.14 and greater](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sdk-download#download_sdk) does now support bitcode however the SDK itself does not support watchOS or tvOS, what I stated about the Measurement Protocol is still true, someone even worked up an [example](https://github.com/analytics-pros/GA-Tracker-for-Apple-tvOS)

Comment: I have a Swift Package for doing this here:
https://github.com/brightdigit/GampKit